using aux file for multiple volumes
I'm writing multi-volume book for a publisher who has an in-house LaTeX support person but I'm a little confused about some of his suggestions on how to handle links from one volume to another. They suggest regular book style.
I don't want to actually link from one volume to another, but just to be able to refer to labels from an earlier book in a later book. I can imagine a workflow like:

publish (print and ebook) Volume 1 that has labels to figures and pages. It's done and published.

prepare Volume 2 which might need to do a \ref or \pageref to labels from that done Volume 1. The need would be to be able to say in Volume 2, "see Figure 4 in Volume 1" not actually link. So a "see Figure~\ref{labelfromV1} in Volume 1"

What I imagine is a final, one-time run at Volume 2 time of both volumes so that the BIG aux file would do the proper pointing from V2 to V1 contents. But then I've got a pdf of two books, rather than 1. And I don't know how to handle two covers, two TOC, etc...


Instead of that, I think that the support person says that parts of the aux file from V1 would be copied and pasted into the preamble of V2 to do the proper job of "see Figure 4 in Volume 1"
Does this make sense? aux files have always been a black box to me and somehow mining it for particular labels seems like a lot of manual work, if even that can be done!
thanks...

Welcome to TeX.SE you can import the .aux files into another volume by using the package xr.sty
